# jQuery datatables select rows with specific data from dataset

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using jQuery DataTables and looking for a way to use a button to select rows from the entire dataset that contain a specific value (in this case "foo").

This is the script I'm using to populate my table:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/pdfmake-0.1.18/dt-1.10.12/b-1.2.2/b-html5-1.2.2/b-print-1.2.2/r-2.1.0/se-1.2.0/datatables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/pdfmake-0.1.18/dt-1.10.12/b-1.2.2/b-html5-1.2.2/b-print-1.2.2/r-2.1.0/se-1.2.0/datatables.min.js"></script>

var oTable = $('#table').DataTable({
  'ajax': {
      url: 'script-to-return-json-row-data.php',
      type: "POST",
      dataSrc: function ( data ) {
              return data;
      },
      'columns': [
        { 
            "data": "name",                   
            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                return data;
        }
       ]

  }
});
```

The sample dataset receive from `script-to-return-json-row-data.php` looks something like this:

`[
["name":"a-name-i-want-to-select","specific-value":"foo"],
["name":"a-name-i-dont-want-to-select","specific-value":"bar"]
]`

In the past I've been able to use the script below to select the rows that contain a specific class

```
$('#select-specific-values-button').click(function(e){
  oTable.rows( {search:'applied'} ).every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop){
        if($(this.node()).hasClass('class-name')){
            $(this.node()).addClass('selected');
        }
  });
});
```

However I'm wondering if there's a way to modify the code above to only select rows where the row data `specific-value` is equal to `foo`.  Any ideas on how I can do this?

I know the code below wont work but this should give a good idea what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
$('#select-specific-values-button').click(function(e){
  oTable.rows( {search:'applied'} ).every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop){
        // if($(this).rowIdx.data.specific-value == 'foo'){
        //     $(this.node()).addClass('selected');
        // }
  });
});
```

Comment: you can use [individual column searching](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up working for me:

```
$('#select-specific-values-button').click(function(e){
   oTable.rows( {search:'applied'} ).every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop){
        if(oTable.row( rowIdx ).data().specific-value == 'foo'){
             $(this.node()).addClass('selected'); 
        }
   });  
});
```

Comment: Great you figured it out! Remember to mark your answer as accepted, perhaps it can help future visitors.